# Tensorflow.js not being able to find model in local storage in async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, local-storage, tensorflow.js

So currently I am trying to use an async function so fetch a file from the project directory and set it to local storage. The have the tensorflow.js function loadLayersModel() grab the file from local storage and load it into a variable called "model".

```
async function tensorFlow() {

                let response = await fetch("./AI-Model/model.json")

                console.log(response);

                var data = await response.json();

                console.log("DATA: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                await localStorage.setItem('saved_model', JSON.stringify(data));


                const model = await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://saved_model');
        }
```

I can view through the developer tools in Chrome that the data is getting correctly assigned to the localstorage, however when the loadLayersModel() is called I get the following error.

```
local_storage.js:208 Uncaught (in promise) Error: In local storage, there is no model with name 'saved_model'
```

My suspicion is that the localStorage.setItem is getting called after loadLayersModel(). But even after the program assigns saved_model to local storage it still doesn't recognize that the saved_model is there in local storage. I can't figure out why this is happening and I'm looking for a way to load in my layers model through my project directory so I don't have to set up a web server.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is with how you are retrieving the data and also note that all `localStorage` calls are synchronous.

```
localStorage.setItem('saved_model', JSON.stringify(data));
const modelFromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem('saved_model');
const JSONSavedModel = JSON.parse(modelFromLocalStorage)
const model = await tf.loadLayersModel(JSONSavedModel);
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error @yudhiesh

`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot proceed with model loading because the IOHandler provided does not have the load method implemented.`

Answer (score 0):

`loadLayersModel` can itself load a model over http(s). This is convenient since it might have to load weight files as well.

Likewise using `model.save` not only saves a model but the weights as well.

Later the model can be saved (respectively retrieved) to (respectively from) the localstorage.

```
await model = tf.loadLayersModel('url/of/model') // here url is './AI-Model/model.json'

// save the model to localstorage

await model.save('localstorage://name-of-model');

// later retrieved the model

await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://name-of-model');
```